# Automate sequence of keys to recover a stuck SSH session

Tags: bash, vim, ssh, tmux

[Close stuck SSH sessions](http://www.arklyffe.com/main/2011/02/01/close-stuck-ssh-sessions/) describes this method, which works great.

> press enter, tilde (~), and then period (.)

This works great, but I always forget the sequence of keys. I use bash, vim, and tmux, but I can't think of a way to automate this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Create a menu option in your terminal emulator. Now of the other programs (bash, vim, and tmux) are responsive at this point.

Comment: A thought: write an `expect` based wrapper on top of `ssh`. When the ssh target computer is unresponsive, send `<CR>~.` to the ssh process. & then instead of standard ssh, use that wrapper to connect...

Comment: My previous comment should say None instead of Now.

Comment: Be careful - if you ssh into a host and then ssh into another host - by entering `<CR>~.` you will close the _outermost_ ssh session rather than the _innermost_ session.  If you want to kill the innermost session, you would need to press `<CR>~..` - in fact, it's one extra dot per 'layer' of ssh sessions.  So, this may be something you don't want to automate.

Comment: Good point on multiple SSH sessions.

Comment: @FDinoff is there a way to keep an external iTerm config file?

Comment: @carl.anderson I believe it should be `<CR>~~.` for second-level sessions and you add tildes for each inner session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think tmux `send-keys` command should do the trick.
Here's a snippet for your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind t send-keys "C-m" "~."
```

Notice `C-m` is provided as a separate argument from tilde and dot. That way it's "recognized" as `Enter`.

I tested this on the (regular, non stuck) ssh session by pressing `prefix + t` and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me. I tested it by adding the option to my tmux config, starting a new tmux session, SSH-ing, stopping my wi-fi, and was able to end the stuck session with `prefix + t`. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work for me, tmux reports 'syntax error'. Same if I just run `send-keys "C-m" "~."` in tmux

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use autokey? works great on Ubuntu. You can get it [here](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/)

The application is well documented. You can assign keyboard abbreviations to the command, so for long commands it comes really handy.
You can also assign window name to execute these abbreviations. For example, for a long command you can save it and assign a key combination to paste this command only in a gtk terminal.